# Nav bar dropping below background image?

Tags: html, css

I have just started creating my site and getting into web development. I was creating a social media nav bar . i wanted to place it in the bottom right side of all my pages. It worked fine except for one which showed the nav bar way below the end of my background image. After several attempts to fix it several other pages also started having the same issue.

leloupdevelopment.com

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Avoid external links and please include on the question the relevant code, enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: thanks, sorry about that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this bit in your CSS:

```css
#social-media-icons {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

This way, it always stays in the bottom of the screen, irrespective of the page size. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should change the z-index but to use that you need to position it to either absolute or relative depending on your element. The higher z-index means your element is going to be on top of the lowest z-index.